# How to call Map methods in onPostExecute?

Tags: java, android, dictionary, asynchronous, inner-classes

I have the following situation, I have a class:

```
public class MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback
```

Which includes the following methods:

```
private void createMarkers(LatLng latLng) {

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);

    map.addMarker(markerOptions);
}

private LatLng getLatLngFromAddress(String address) {

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity());
    List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
    LatLng latLng = null;

    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, 1);

        if(addresses == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Address location = addresses.get(0);
        latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return latLng;
}
```

And at this point I have an inner class in which I download data in the doInBackground method from SQLite, and in onPostExecute I would like to put markers on the map. How can I call these 2 methods in onPostExecute (createMarkers and getLatLngFromAddress)?

```
private static class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {

    private String currentDateForRequest = "";
    private IRoutesStore database;
    private List<String> allAddresses = new ArrayList<>();

    public getDataTask(String currentDateForRequest, IRoutesStore database) {
        this.currentDateForRequest = currentDateForRequest;
        this.database = database;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        
        //getData from database
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> addresses) {

        for(String address: addresses) {
            createMarkers(getLatLngFromAddress(address)); //I can"t call this methods
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could pass `MapFragment` as parameter to the constructor of `getDataTask` and then call the methods on the `MapFragment` object

Answer (score 0):

Makr your map globally
And use this.map